# Can't pass Firebaseuser object to a new screen in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

After creating the user in signup screen, I want to pass the user object to a new screen. But the user object is always null in the new screen though user creation is successful. I know current user can be accessed with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` . But why is the user object null when it is passed from signup screen to a new screen?

```
   Future<FirebaseUser> signUpUserWithEmailPass(
      String email, String pass) async {
    try {
      var authResult = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: pass,
      );
      print("On Try");
      return authResult.user;
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      throw Exception(errors.toString());
    }
  }
```

Navigation to a new screen :

```
  void navigateToHomePage(BuildContext context, FirebaseUser user) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return HomePage(user);
    }));
  }
```

**Update : Solved**
I am using BLoC pattern & I forgot to set user object in the state class's constructor. That's actually creating the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's null because it's `asynchronous`, the method `signUpUserWithEmailPass` returns a `Future`, then when you call it you can pass the result to the `navigateToHomeScreen`:

```
signUpUserWithEmailPass.then((result) => {
      print(result);
      navigateToHomePage(context,result);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, its asynchronous. I'm using BLoC pattern for creating users. So, basically navigation is being done based on the state. If state is UserCreationSuccessful,  only then I'm navigating. User creation is done in the bloc class.

Comment: Oops! I just missed to set user object in my state class's constructor. That's actually creating problem!

Comment: Are u using the bloc pattern with provider?

Comment: flutter_bloc package for BLoC pattern

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to Asynchronous function. The user object could've been passed before you got the result.

So Kindly wait for `signUpUserWithEmailPass()` function complete first and then assign it to user object like this:

```
user = await signUpUserWithEmailPass("email", "password");
navigateToHomePage(context, user);
```

for this you have to make the parent function `async`.

Otherwise do this:

```
signUpUserWithEmailPass.then((user) {
  navigateToHomePage(context, user);
});
```

Hope it helps