# Firebase Authentication in Flutter Check if user is a new user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the following login method and I am trying to use the `isNewUser` function to push a new screen:

```
Future<void> googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      if (googleUser == null) return;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
       return const SignUpNewUser();
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Error"),
        content: Text('Failed to sign in with Google: ${e.message}'),
      );
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
A value of type 'SignUpNewUser' can't be returned from the method 'googleLogin' because it has a return type of 'Future<void>'.
```

I'm pretty sure that I placed it in the correct spot to implement the function, but I have no idea how to do it in a Future.

Comment: The issue with pushing to a new screen may be due to the asynchronous function. You may refer to the following Stackoverflow cases.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518783/cant-pass-firebaseuser-object-to-a-new-screen-in-flutter
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463574/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-if-so-show-other-screen   Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the return type, you need change the type from void to dynamic.

```
Future<dynamic> googleLogin() async {...}
```

Comment: This clears the error but does not push to the new screen. Do I need to change the return function?

Comment: Where you call this function? You need the context to use Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpNewUser()),
  );

Comment: I already tried that but the Conext throws an error in relation to the build context. ```The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.```

Comment: You can put the code when you call the navigator.push, please?

Comment: ```UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
       return Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpNewUser()), );
      } ```

Comment: I posted the code in the above comment

Comment: This function is inside build method of stateless or stateful widget? Or is inside other class?

Comment: It's in a custom class(AuthService). I keep all of my UI and business logic separated. I use a StreamBuilder in a different file for my AuthRouting

Comment: Perfect, I understand, where you call the googleLogin() function? You can put this code

Comment: I call it in multiple places. Here is the StreamBuilder to check AuthStatus: ```return StreamBuilder(
      stream: AuthService().userStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text('');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('error'),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return const HomeScreenUser();
        } else {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: HomeScreenPublic(key: key,),```

Comment: I also have a button on the login page to initalize the SignIn: ```GoogleLoginButton(
              text: 'Sign in with Google',
              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.google,
              color: const Color(0xff262626),
              loginMethod: AuthService().googleLogin,
            ),```

Comment: Do yo need pass the context when you instance this function and then use this context to push a new router. Ex: AuthService().googleLogin(context) and then inside of Future<dynamic> googleLogin(context){...}

Comment: I do not need the context passed through my login buttons in order for the auth flow to work. The actual authentication works but I am just adding this feature for my firestore db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239248/discussion-between-db-cooper-and-felipe-vergara).

Answer (score 0):

you can return a widget directly but that doesn't makes sense so you need to use `Navigator` in order to push to a new screen.

1. Add `context` as parameter in the method `googleLogin()`
2. Use this `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>your_new_screen()),);`
   in the condition `userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser`

   In the above replace `your_new_screen()` with the widget you have returned before ie. `SignUpNewUser()`

Comment: Your solution throws an error when the login button is presses ```The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'AuthService.googleLogin'
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => Future<void> from Function 'googleLogin':.
Tried calling: AuthService.googleLogin()
Found: AuthService.googleLogin(dynamic) => Future<void>```